# python django - ImportError: No module named lib

Tags: django, python-2.7, google-app-engine

i'm a newbie in this field. I develops web application with google app engine using django framework. i have a troubleshot about python lib dir problem... ImportError: no module named...

```
ROOT
├── lib
│   ├── django
│   ├── pytz
│   ├── wanttousing_lib
│   └── ...
├── mysite
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── controllers.py
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── views.py
│   ├── templates
│   │   └── like
│   │        ├── index.html
│   │        └── _likehelpers.html
│   └── ....
├── test
│   ├── like
│   │   ├── models_tests.py
│   │   └── controllers_tests.py
│   └── ....
├── static
│   ├── css
│   └── js
├── app.yaml
├── manage.py
├── appengine_config.py
└── requirements.txt
```

in this dir, failed runserver .. 
in my test code controllers_tests.py

```
`from wanttousing_lib import example_module`
```

importError wanttousing_lib..........

but if I move my wanttousing_lib to ROOT dir, it works.....

```
ROOT
├── lib
│   ├── django
│   ├── pytz
│   
│   └── ...
├── mysite
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── controllers.py
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── views.py
│   ├── templates
│   │   └── like
│   │        ├── index.html
│   │        └── _likehelpers.html
│   └── ....
├── test
│   ├── like
│   │   ├── models_tests.py
│   │   └── controllers_tests.py
│   └── ....
├── static
│   ├── css
│   └── js
├── app.yaml
├── manage.py
├── appengine_config.py
├── requirements.txt
└── wanttousing_lib  <--- moved
```

how can i fix it? please help...

Comment: Do  your `wanttousing_lib ` contains `__init__.py`?

Comment: yes. wanttolib is twilio which is installed using pip. it contains __init__.py.

Answer (score 1):

ensure you have `__init__.py` in corresponding folder..

and try this, `from lib.wanttousing_lib import example_module`

because your `wanttousing_lib` was reside in `lib` folder.. if you move outside `lib.` not required.

Comment: wanttolib is twilio.

Comment: in appengine_config.py , add.vendor('lib')

Comment: you're talking about folder structure in django.. if not what do you want exactly?